# How to iterate over the results of a generator function

Tags: javascript, node.js, generator, ecmascript-6

Is there a better way to iterate over the results of a generator, my for loop is ugly:

```
for(let job = readyJob.next(); !job.done; job = readyJob.next()){ }
```

In context there is a generator function that can determine if there is a batch of work, consisting of 1..* jobs (the generator may also return no jobs in the batch).  There is a continuous loop that instantiates the generator and iterates over the batch doing work on the job (logging).

Is there a more elegant solution to this iteration  problem.  I mean this looks like a traditional iterator from Java/C# which isn't bad.  Something like an "each" would be super readable...  That's my hope anyhow.

```
 let getReadyJob = function *(instance){
    let numJobs = 7 ; // getRandomInt(0, 10) ;
    for(let i = 0; i < numJobs; i++) {
        yield {
            jobId: '' + instance + '::' + i,
            jobReadyOn: (new Date()).valueOf()
        };
    }
}
```

then

```
while(true){
    let readyJob = getReadyJob()

    for(let job = readyJob.next(); !job.done; job = readyJob.next()){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(job.value)) ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, if your environment already supports [**`for...of`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of):

```
for (var job of readyJob) {
  // ...
}
```

If not, have seen this a couple of times:

```
var next;
while (!(next = readyJob.next()).done) {
   var job = next.value;
   // ...
}
```

Comment: The "for of" is exactly what I was looking for (pun intended) - thank you.  I would lump the "while loop" option in with the  "for loop" option I mentioned as very C++/Java/C# like - sure it works but there's an awful lot going on on that line and its not super readable...

Comment: Well, `while` is quite idiomatic. But `for..of` beats it readability-wise - and is a perfect pair to generators. )

Comment: What about iterate with an index?

Comment: @Weilory: Just keep your own counter.

Answer (score 2):

`for ... of` is the elegant solution but not overall supported, however `while (!(next = cursor.next()).done) {` is a very cryptic, and one might ask himself, how come `(var x = someFunctionCall())` is evaluated to `true` and 
another would answer `welcome to javascript`.

For that reason and to and give the answer another shape, it can also be done using a recursive function.

```
function loopThose(items) {
    const item = items.next();

    // doStuff(item);

    if (!item.done) {
        loopThose(items);
    }
}
```

A true benefit is when async, try catch and custom continue condition come into play:

```
async function printKeys(items) {
    try {
       const item = await items.next();
       // doStuff(item);
       if (isConditionFulfil(item)) {
          await this.printKeys(items);
       }
    } catch (e){

    }
}
```

Where a generator function yields promises that might fail:

```
function * list(){
  for (var i = 0; i<10; i++){
     yield fetch(buildResourceUrl(i)).then(res => res.json())
  }
}
```